# PHPMailer Undefined type 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer'

Tags: php, phpmailer

When i try to type `new PHPMailer(true);` Then its keep giving me the same error:

`Undefined type 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer'.`

Can you tell whats the problem? Thanks!

**Code:**

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Host = "smtp.rackhost.hu";
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Port = 465;

$mail->Username = "mail@jarkoricsi.hu";
$mail->Password = "Teszt123";

$mail->setFrom("mail@jarkoricsi.hu", "Djalms");
$mail->addAddress("alma.katica222@gmail.com");

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $message;

$mail->send();

echo "email sent";
?>
```

The username, Password and the setFrom is empty to keep privacy.

Comment: Did you get an errors or warnings, e.g. from the `require` statements failing, or anything like that?

Comment: Its working, but it keeps throwing error 504 gateway-timeout now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've now managed to install PHPMailer with composer (which would explain why you were getting the class not found error), I expect the 504 is caused by this combination of settings:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
$mail->Port = 465;
```

That's asking it to do explicit TLS on a port expecting implicit TLS, which will not work, but might take a long time to fail, leading to the 504 error. The difference is [explained in the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#encryption-flavours), but either of these two combinations should work:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
$mail->Port = 587;
```

or

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
$mail->Port = 465;
```